# Commerce - Live Environment - "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, error-message, error

I have a site and been tested locally and on staging server and it checks out fine.
I have moved it to the clients live server (Windows 2016) but when I hit the pay button via dummy gateway or Worldpay Gateway I get the error:

Trying to get property of non-object:

[image]

Why is this only occuring on the Live Environment - PHP version is the same locally as the server - 7.1.7

Comment: Are you running the latest Commerce version? https://craftcommerce.com/changelog

Comment: Yes installed latest earlier today

Comment: Weird... if you `die($billingAddress->getState());` right before line 234 there, does it output anything?

Comment: Weird alright! - no just a blank screen is i put that in.

Comment: I can't see how it should even pass the `if ($billingAddress->getState())` conditional if it is returning empty/null.

Comment: Yep I see what you are saying - strange. I put in `echo($billingAddress->getState());` before the `if ($billingAddress->getState())` conditional and it gets to the next stage fine.  But if i remove it I get the error again.
What could the cause be - works fine on local and staging - just the live server i get that error.

Comment: Can you try deleting the order/cart in the control panel and try again?

Comment: Does the production box have APC/opcache (or any other PHP byte level caching extension) installed?  Only thing I can think of is it's either that or a Windows/PHP bug.

Comment: Had tried the deleting orders but no success either. 
wincache was enabled but I disabled but it has made no difference.

Comment: Ok - so played with it a little more - before the `if ($billingAddress->getState())` conditional I have put in 2 lines: `echo($billingAddress->getState());` and `die($billingAddress->getState());` I have tried cecking out 3 times and those times I have checked out it has displayed a state on the screen - first, `Minnesota`then `Mississippi` and then `Missouri`.